# Eclipse Helios + Android content assist not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I've got ADK 16.0.1 and the Eclipse Helios (3.6.2) which I updated this morning.

I can't get Android methods to suggest when I do content assist.

The best advice I've been able to find is to update everything to the latest versions and the problem will be automagically solved.

Can anyone post what they have done specifically to fix this?

Mark

Comment: Haven't updated yet, but interested in the solution to this one before I do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the ADT  Plugin and SDK Tools

Comment: Turns out the solution was simple:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107515/eclipse-content-assist-not-working-with-android

I did this and it started working.

Comment: Some times creating a new wokspace fixes such issues

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the solution was simple: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4107515](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107515) I did this and it started working.