# Eclipse Content Assist Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

Lately I have been having more and more issues with the content assist in Eclipse.  In some of my projects, I get no proposals from the content assist, and in other projects I get some or all of the expected proposals.  Typically there is no "error" in Eclipse, but here is an example of one when I do get an error:

> "Content Assist" did not complete normally.  Please see the log for more information.
>   Pb(324) The type android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have tried the various suggestions (including but not limited to the two below) from similar questions with no luck.  I have even gone as far as removing and re-installing eclipse and re-creating the projects without any of the Eclipse metadata or settings.

- [Eclipse Content Assist not working with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107515/eclipse-content-assist-not-working-with-android)
- [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Android Development Toolkit
Version: 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

Error Log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-05-22 09:25:34.061
!MESSAGE Pb(324) The type android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.handle(ProblemReporter.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.isClassPathCorrect(ProblemReporter.java:4039)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1335)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.impl.Engine.accept(Engine.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.availableFields(ReferenceBinding.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalExtendedCompletionContext.searchVisibleFields(InternalExtendedCompletionContext.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalExtendedCompletionContext.searchVisibleVariablesAndMethods(InternalExtendedCompletionContext.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalExtendedCompletionContext.computeVisibleElementBindings(InternalExtendedCompletionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalExtendedCompletionContext.getVisibleElements(InternalExtendedCompletionContext.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionContext.getVisibleElements(InternalCompletionContext.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.getAssignableElements(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.guessParameters(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.computeGuessingCompletion(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.computeReplacementString(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.getReplacementString(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.apply(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaMethodCompletionProposal.apply(JavaMethodCompletionProposal.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.apply(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.apply(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.apply(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.insertProposal(CompletionProposalPopup.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$21(CompletionProposalPopup.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$2.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.showProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.showPossibleCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1656)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor$AdaptedSourceViewer.doOperation(CompilationUnitEditor.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction$1.run(ContentAssistAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction.run(ContentAssistAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerWrapper.execute(LegacyHandlerWrapper.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.press(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.processKeyEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.filterKeySequenceBindings(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.access$3(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4640)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4528)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2531)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: What appears in the error log?

Comment: i've attached the error log above

Comment: I should also note the android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks comes from the ActionBarSherlock library, not the standard support library.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also tried installing Eclipse 4.2M7, and I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up upgrading the ActionBarSherlock library to the latest 4.1 (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and it has fixed my eclipse troubles.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Restore defaults

Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Advanced >> Restore defaults

Comment: Problem still exists. I closed all eclipse windows and re-launched just to make sure the settings stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with projects that used the V4 compatibility library when it was updated. Try removing the project dependency on the library, restarting Eclipse, and then adding the dependency back in. (I *think* this is what I did to resolve the issue, but if that doesn't work, I'll try to think of what else I might have done.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, with Pb(324) message. It turned out, that reading the message with understanding was enough to fix it. However what I did first was going to stackoverflow. No good :)

In my groovy project the dependent libraries were not automatically visible by autocompletion. Not sure why, I'm new to this stuff. So I was adding them manually. But I did not add manually the indirect dependencies. The error message specifies the class causing the problem. **I added a reference to the jar containing the problematic class** and bingo - no more code assist errors.

To be specific: *Project, Properties, Java Build Path, Libraries, Add External JARs*. Then I pointed to the directory, where gradle downloaded the lib.

Answer (score 0):

For me updating Eclipse worked.