# Error with autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, go, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse, goclipse

I am running Eclipse 4.6.3 with GoClipse and NodeClipse installed. I have configured Go in Preferences -> Go.

I want **autocomplete** to work for Go. However, it is giving me the error: **writing to process input broken pipe**

See screenshots below for error and configuration.

[image: Error]

[image: Go]

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I would seriously reconsider using Eclipse. Instead look at gogland if you want a complete IDE.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk agreed but for unmentioned reasons here I have to use Eclipse unfortunately

Comment: some stacks you should check as this error doesn't seem language specific. This is more of a general issue with eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871947/eclipse-warning-problems-during-content-assist
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706430/eclipse-content-assist-error
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367694/

That all being said and shown, you will likely have better turn around asking  in an eclipse only community.

Comment: I guess the executables for  `gocode`, `guru` and `godef` that you specify in the preferences were incorrect. The executables should be `$GOPATH/bin/gocode`, `$GOPATH/bin/guru` and `$GOPATH/bin/godef` (replace `$GOPATH` with real path). Don't forget to install those tools.

Comment: @putu is correct. This is at least part of your problem. The `.go` files are most definitely not executable.

Comment: @putu your comment actually solved the problem for me. I already installed those but just didn't point to the right places. If you post an answer I will accept it

Comment: The answer is provided by @mhutter. Please accept it.

Comment: @putu done thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least on the second page, all of the paths seem wrong. You supplied the path to the *source code* where the dialog asks for the path to the *executable*.

To make sure you have all the tools installed run the following commands in the terminal:

```
go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru
go get -u github.com/rogpeppe/godef
```

Now, for each of the tools run

```
which <tool>
# example:
which guru
# => /Users/user/gocode/bin/gocode
```

Copy the output into the `Executable:` field in the config screen.

For gofmt you should be able to simply tick "Use default location"

Comment: I just noticed the same was discussed in the comments (which I blatantly ignored). If @putu wants to add this as an answer I'll delete mine.